# How to delete all table rows in a LightSwitch Application

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am new to the LightSwitch framework and I have to delete all of the data from a table before importing data from csv file into the table.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of doing that on [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb48bd18-d9d3-48a6-9186-3caa7d25595c/delete-all-records-lightswitch-intrinsic-table) which I'll precis here in case of link rot. It works directly on the Data Workspace to avoid the issue of only the current page of a visual collection being "available" unless you mess with the paging in code. Assuming the entity type is ZoneRate,

```
    Private Sub Method_Execute()
        For Each zoneRate In Me.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ZoneRates
            CType(zoneRate, ZoneRate).Delete()
        Next
        Me.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.SaveChanges()
    End Sub
```